# This range is repeated or overlapped

Tags: sas

Now the question I have is I have a bigger problem as I am getting "this range is repeated or overlapped"... To be specific my values of label are repeating I mean my format has repeated values like a=aa b=aa c=as kind of. How do I resolve this error. When I use the hlo=M as muntilqbel option it gives double the data...

I am mapping like below. 
 Santhan=Santhan
Chintu=Santhan

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Provide more background into what you are doing.  If you are referencing another question then add a link. Why are you creating a FORMAT?  How are you planning to use the FORMAT?  Is a FORMAT even what you need?

Comment: Your examples do NOT have multiple decodes for the same code.  Multiple decodes for the same code is what the multi-label is designed to handle.  Multiple codes that map to the same decode can be handled by a normal format.

Comment: Yes I need format. My intension is to take the hard values of proc format value out and make it an entry in text file. I am reading the data from file and loading it to dataset. Now I am formating or mapping them for further processing. My example here now has like below. ABC=ABC BCD=BCD BCD1=BCD BCD2=BCD BCD3=BCD AND SO ON. Now I am doing format dynamically by loading the data of infile to dataset...

Comment: If you have FORMAT to start with then use CNTLOUT= option to make a dataset. Then it is easy to make a text file. Otherwise why are you adding the complication of a FORMAT if you are not actually using it as a FORMAT?

Comment: I am using cntlin = dataset option. I have succeeded for 4 formats. My last format is text= text format where it is thowing me error as I said above ... My example data is as below.              ABC=ABC BCD=BCD BCD1=BCD BCD2=BCD BCD3=BCD ...........     Please do let me know how to solve this issue now. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are getting an error then post the actual error message from the SAS log.  You might want to eliminate the duplicate labels before trying to create a format.  Perhaps your START column is too short and truncation is causing duplicates.

Comment: You keep saying opposite things. Do you want to create a format from data (or text file source)?  Or create a text file from a format?  HOW are you using the format in either case?  Are you using with PUT() function to generate decoded values?  Are you attaching it to variables using a FORMAT statement in either data or proc step?

Comment: To do what you are asking, is done if you can place your data into Data set, two steps process 1- Get your raw data into data set 2- Use above data set to get desired format so let do this-

*step 1-;

DATA fmt;
 Infile "Textfile.txt" DSD ;
 Retain fmtname '$myfmt';  /*myfmt is what your format name*/;
 Length start $2 label $50;
 Input start label ;
RUN; 
Now since above code will create a dataset with Male female information use same dataset to create your format.

*Step2:

PROC FORMAT CNTLIN=fmt;
RUN; 
I am doing the above

Comment: I am taking the data from the file as a source and creating format.  I am getting the error like this range is repeated or overlapped. My text file has ABC'='ABC' 'BCD'='BCD' 'BCD1'='BCD' 'BCD2'='BCD' this data. Like this I have 2000 records in input and I am getting error at this format. Where as when I said 1=a 2=b 3=c kind of it works but char to chat it throws me error. My data is exactly like ABC'='ABC' 'BCD'='BCD' 'BCD1'='BCD' 'BCD2'='BCD in input file

Comment: Why did you place `....` at the point in the log that is most informative ?

Answer (score 0):

To convert data to a FORMAT use the CNTLIN= option on PROC FORMAT. But first make sure the data describes a valid format.  So read the data from the file.

```
data myfmt ;
  infile 'myfile.txt' dsd truncover ;
  length fmtname $32 start $100 value $200 ;
  fmtname = '$MYFMT';
  input start value ;
run;
```

Make sure to set the lengths of START and VALUE to be long enough for any actual values your source file might have.

Then make sure it is sorted and you do not have duplicate codes (START values).

```
proc sort data=myfmt out=myfmt_clean nodupkey ;
  by start;
run;
```

The SAS log will show if any observations were deleted because of duplicate START values.

If you do have duplicate values then examine the dataset or original text file to understand why and determine how you want to handle the duplicates.  The PROC SORT step above will keep just one of the duplicates.  You might just has exact duplicates, in which case keeping only one is fine.  Or you might want to collapse the duplicate observations into a single observation and concatenate the multiple decodes into one long decode.

If you want you can add a record that will add the functionality of the `OTHER` keyword of the `VALUE` statement in `PROC FORMAT`.  You can use that to set a default value, like 'Value not found', to decode any value you might encounter that was not in your original source file.

```
data myfmt_final;
  set myfmt_clean end=eof;
  output;
  if eof then do;
     start = ' ';
     label = 'Value not found';
     hlo = 'O' ;
     output;
  end;
run;
```

Then use PROC FORMAT to make the format from the cleaned up data file.

```
proc format cntlin = myfmt_final;
run;
```

To convert a FORMAT to a dataset use the CNTLOUT= option on PROC FORMAT.

For example if you had created this format previously.

```
proc format ;
  value $myfmt 'ABC'='ABC' 'BCD'='BCD' 'BCD1'='BCD' 'BCD2'='BCD' ;
run;
```

then you can use another PROC FORMAT step to make a dataset.  Use the SELECT statement if you format catalog has more than one format defined and you just want one (or some) of them.

```
proc format cntlout=myfmt ;
   select $myfmt ;
run;
```

Then you can use that dataset to easily make a text file.  For example a comma delimited file.

```
data _null_;
  set myfmt ;
  file 'myfmt.txt' dsd ;
  put start label;
run;
```

The result would be a text file that looks like this:

```
ABC,ABC
BCD,BCD
BCD1,BCD
BCD2,BCD
```

Comment: proc format ;
  value $myfmt 'ABC'='ABC' 'BCD'='BCD' 'BCD1'='BCD' 'BCD2'='BCD' ;
run;. This is like a hard way. I am passing the values ABC=ABC etc from a text file that is delimited. Now I want map them up where I am getting error. I have 3000 values and that cannot be in ahard way so loading that data from text file. I want exactly the reverse way of what your answer was

Comment: They the code in the updated answer which has extra steps to make sure the dataset can be used to make a format.  Make sure you know what is in your text file and that it is actually something that can be used to make a format.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because you have the same code that maps to two different categories. I'm going to guess you likely did not import your data correctly from your text file and ended up getting some values truncated but without the full process it's an educated guess.

This will work fine:

```
proc format;
value $ test
'a'='aa' 'b'='aa' 'c'='as'
;
run;
```

This version will not work, because `a` is mapped to two different values, so SAS will not know which one to use.

```
proc format;
value $ badtest
'a'='aa'
'a' = 'ba'
'b' = 'aa' 
'c' = 'as';
run;
```

This generates the error regarding overlaps in your data.

The way to fix this is to find the duplicates and determine which code they should actually map to. PROC SORT can be used to get your duplicate records.